# Como usar o "import" adequadamente em uma aplicação node.js com typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Boa tarde. Estou escrevendo uma API Rest usando `node.js` e `typescript`, porém estou tendo problemas em usar o `import` em algumas partes do programa.

por exemplo em minha **server.ts** eu tenho:

```
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
```

(Que funciona sem problemas.)

e eu queria muda-lá para:

```
import { connectDB } from "./config/db";
```

porém eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Could not find a declaration file for module './config/db'. 'd:/documentos/projetos/node/Contact_Keeper/config/db.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)

**db.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");

const connectDB = async () => {

try{
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    console.log("MongoDB Connected.")

}catch(err){
    console.log(err.message);
    //ends with a failure
    process.exit(1);
}
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

> **Eu estou usando `module.exports`, então não entendo porque ele não reconhece como um modulo.**

Agora, em uma outra parte do meu código, eu estou tendo outro problema com o `import`, na `rota de user` Eu estou tentando trazer uma `model user do mongoose`, Mas quando eu tento mudar de `const user = require("../models/User");` para `import { user }  from "../models/User";` eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Module '"../../Contact_Keeper/models/User"' has no exported member 'UserSchema'.ts(2305)

Porém eu tenho sim um exports ali, tanto que com `require()` funciona sem problemas.

**Model User Mongoose**

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Se você está usando TS, use a sintaxe de exportação do TS

Comment: @Costamilam esse é o objetivo da minha pergunta, estou tentando usar o import do TS mas tenho esses erros, não quero usar o require, mas estou usando enquanto não consigo solucionar os problemas com o import.

Comment: O problema ao importar é porque não está **exportando** com o TS

Comment: @Costamilam realmente, não tinha reparado que a exportação seria diferente no TS, consegui arrumar tudo aqui. Muito obrigado!